# Usage of Crypto Library (Speck)

Tags: arduino-uno, library

I really want to understand how can I use this library for my purposes.

I'm trying to encrypt a message that comes through the serial port of the Arduino, and send it through another serial port. But I'm having issues understanding how to use the library.
I have read the documentation of the library, but I still get errors, I need a little help with this.

This is the code I have (without involving the serial ports), initially I wanted to check if I could define my strings and use them in another way instead of using the TestVector Function:

```
 #include <Crypto.h>
 #include <Speck.h>
 #include <SpeckSmall.h>
 #include <SpeckTiny.h>
 #include <string.h>

 struct EncryptText
 {
     const char *name;
     byte key[32];
     byte plaintext[16];
     byte ciphertext[16];
 };

 EncryptText test ;

   static TestCipher {

   test.name = "Speck-128-ECB";
   test.key = {0x0f, 0x0e, 0x0d, 0x0c, 0x0b, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x08,
                     0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00};
   test.plaintext = {0x6c, 0x61, 0x76, 0x69, 0x75, 0x71, 0x65, 0x20,
                     0x74, 0x69, 0x20, 0x65, 0x64, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x20};
  test.ciphertext = {0xa6, 0x5d, 0x98, 0x51, 0x79, 0x78, 0x32, 0x65,
                     0x78, 0x60, 0xfe, 0xdf, 0x5c, 0x57, 0x0d, 0x18};
   }

Speck speck;
SpeckSmall speckSmall;
SpeckTiny speckTiny;

byte buffer[16];

//void testCipher(BlockCipher *cipher, const struct TestVector *test, size_t keySize, bool decryption = true)
void testCipher(BlockCipher *cipher, size_t keySize, bool decryption = true)

{

    Serial.print(" Encryption ... ");
    cipher->setKey(key, keySize);
    cipher->encryptBlock(buffer, plaintext);

    for(byte b=0; b<16; b++)
   {
      Serial.print(buffer[b], HEX);
   }

    if (memcmp(buffer, ciphertext, 16) == 0)
        Serial.println("Passed");
    else
        Serial.println("Failed");

    if (!decryption)
        return;


    Serial.print(" Decryption ... ");
    cipher->decryptBlock(buffer, ciphertext);

    for(byte b=0; b<16; b++)
   {
      Serial.print(buffer[b], HEX);
   }
    if (memcmp(buffer, plaintext, 16) == 0)
        Serial.println("Passed");
    else
        Serial.println("Failed");
}
```

I'm getting the error: "exit status 1 'TestCipher' does not name a type"

EDIT: The full error that I get is:

```
 Speck_4-08-2017:27: error: 'TestCipher' does not name a type    static
 TestCipher {
           ^ Speck_4-08-2017.ino: In function 'void testCipher(BlockCipher*, size_t, bool)': Speck_4-08-2017:62: error:
 'key' was not declared in this scope
      cipher->setKey(key, keySize);
                     ^ Speck_4-08-2017:63: error: 'plaintext' was not declared in this scope
      cipher->encryptBlock(buffer, plaintext);
                                   ^ Speck_4-08-2017:70: error: 'ciphertext' was not declared in this scope
      if (memcmp(buffer, ciphertext, 16) == 0)
                         ^ Speck_4-08-2017:80: error: 'ciphertext' was not declared in this scope
      cipher->decryptBlock(buffer, ciphertext);
                                   ^ Speck_4-08-2017.ino: In function 'void perfCipher(BlockCipher*, const TestVector*, size_t, bool)':
 Speck_4-08-2017:104: error: 'key2' was not declared in this scope
          cipher->setKey(key2, keySize);
                         ^ Speck_4-08-2017.ino: In function 'void setup()': Speck_4-08-2017:158: error: 'testVectorSpeck128' was not
 declared in this scope
      testCipher(&speck, &testVectorSpeck128, 16);
                          ^ exit status 1 'TestCipher' does not name a type
```

Any guidance would be very helpful.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arduino SE! Could you please provide the full error message?

Comment: I just made an edit adding the full error message I get.

Comment: Which version of the library are you using? (Github link would do just fine)

Comment: Sorry, I should have included it: https://github.com/rweather/arduinolibs/tree/master/libraries/Crypto

Comment: Does the [TestSpeck](https://github.com/rweather/arduinolibs/blob/master/libraries/Crypto/examples/TestSpeck/TestSpeck.ino) example included with the library compile without errors?

Comment: Yes, it does, and the encryption is done correctly, but I wanted to try a way of manipulating the strings that will be encrypted. This way I could read a serial port and make the encryption.

Comment: Okay, that proves the library and IDE is installed correctly. You don't want to spend time debugging your code when the library or IDE itself is broken. Please see my answer how to start fixing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error looks like this

```
 Speck_4-08-2017:27: error: 'TestCipher' does not name a type    static
 TestCipher {
```

Further errors are basically all caused by that one wrongly written declaration. It could be fixed by declaring the first struct properly.
Compare this example code you have

```
struct TestVector
{
    const char *name;
    byte key[32];
    byte plaintext[16];
    byte ciphertext[16];
};

static TestVector const testVectorSpeck256 = {
    .name        = "Speck-256-ECB",
    .key         = {0x1f, 0x1e, 0x1d, 0x1c, 0x1b, 0x1a, 0x19, 0x18,
                    0x17, 0x16, 0x15, 0x14, 0x13, 0x12, 0x11, 0x10,
                    0x0f, 0x0e, 0x0d, 0x0c, 0x0b, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x08,
                    0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00},
    .plaintext   = {0x65, 0x73, 0x6f, 0x68, 0x74, 0x20, 0x6e, 0x49,
                    0x20, 0x2e, 0x72, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x70},
    .ciphertext  = {0x41, 0x09, 0x01, 0x04, 0x05, 0xc0, 0xf5, 0x3e,
                    0x4e, 0xee, 0xb4, 0x8d, 0x9c, 0x18, 0x8f, 0x43}
};
```

and your code

```
struct EncryptText
 {
     const char *name;
     byte key[32];
     byte plaintext[16];
     byte ciphertext[16];
 };

 EncryptText test ;
   static TestCipher {

   test.name = "Speck-128-ECB";
   test.key = {0x0f, 0x0e, 0x0d, 0x0c, 0x0b, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x08,
                     0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00};
   test.plaintext = {0x6c, 0x61, 0x76, 0x69, 0x75, 0x71, 0x65, 0x20,
                     0x74, 0x69, 0x20, 0x65, 0x64, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x20};
  test.ciphertext = {0xa6, 0x5d, 0x98, 0x51, 0x79, 0x78, 0x32, 0x65,
                     0x78, 0x60, 0xfe, 0xdf, 0x5c, 0x57, 0x0d, 0x18};
   }
```

You wrote `EncryptText test;` by specifying the type `EncryptText` you defined before and a name `test`, but now, you can assign to test by just using `test.` + variable name and nothing else (no `static TestCipher{}`). Or you could use what the example does, it basically just skips the `EncryptText test;` part and puts it on one line, like `static TestVector const testVectorSpeck128 = {` and assigns inside the curly brackets just using `.` + variable name (without `test` or `testVectorSpeck128`).

Now, the second error

```
 'key' was not declared in this scope
      cipher->setKey(key, keySize);
```

is that the variable `key` is not defined in the function `testCipher` just like the error says, you have to define that variable or use the right one, in the example it was done using a function parameter (you commented out) `TestVector *test`, it was dereferenced and accessed with `test->key`. I assume you've properly defined that struct now, there's no need to deal with pointers and with direct reference to the data you can use it elsewhere by just using something like this

```
cipher->setKey(test.key, keySize);
```

rest of the errors are of similar fashion and can be fixed by just adding `test.` like I showed. If you fix those errors rest should be simple already.

As you are just learning, take small steps modifying the examples and use the `Verify` button as often as possible, Arduino IDE also has a button to autoformat code, use it, makes your code more readable for you and everyone else.

Comment: I managed to compile my code without errors, but now the encryption is not working as it should. Should I create another question for that or edit this one?

Comment: @LuzA I guess you can ask a new question, but maybe you can fit it here into the comments?

Comment: I think I will ask a new question, because I would need to include the code I have right now and well, it's also a different situation that the one I asked in this one.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to create a struct and initialize it. Like this:

```
struct EncryptText
{
    const char *name;
    byte key[32];
    byte plaintext[16];
    byte ciphertext[16];
};

EncryptText test = {
    "Speck-128-ECB",
    {0x0f, 0x0e, 0x0d, 0x0c, 0x0b, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x08,
                     0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00},
    {0x6c, 0x61, 0x76, 0x69, 0x75, 0x71, 0x65, 0x20,
                     0x74, 0x69, 0x20, 0x65, 0x64, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x20},
    {0xa6, 0x5d, 0x98, 0x51, 0x79, 0x78, 0x32, 0x65,
                     0x78, 0x60, 0xfe, 0xdf, 0x5c, 0x57, 0x0d, 0x18}
};
```

Then it appears you want to use that object. Note that to access each member of the struct you have to use dot notation (ex: `test.key`):

```
void testCipher(BlockCipher *cipher, size_t keySize, bool decryption = true)
{
    Serial.print(" Encryption ... ");
    cipher->setKey(test.key, keySize);
    cipher->encryptBlock(buffer, test.plaintext);

    for(byte b=0; b<16; b++)
    {
        Serial.print(buffer[b], HEX);
    }

    if (memcmp(buffer, test.ciphertext, 16) == 0)
        Serial.println("Passed");
    else
        Serial.println("Failed");

    if (!decryption)
        return;

    Serial.print(" Decryption ... ");
    cipher->decryptBlock(buffer, test.ciphertext);

    for(byte b=0; b<16; b++)
    {
        Serial.print(buffer[b], HEX);
    }
    if (memcmp(buffer, test.plaintext, 16) == 0)
        Serial.println("Passed");
    else
        Serial.println("Failed");
}
```